# Consolidating two electricity meters?

Tags: electrical, uk, meter

Today, we got the keys to our new house. I was taking meter readings, when I spotted a note directing me to a *second* meter. This is located at the other end of the house, in it's own cupboard, with it's own consumer board. After some enquirers, I have ascertained that both are active, although oddly being supplied by two different companies.

It is a reasonably old house (even by UK standards) and was at some point actually two small cottages, which were knocked through at some point in it's history. This, combined with the locations of the meters, makes me suspect that the two original houses may retain distinct, isolated, electrical systems.

Some questions:

1. Is my hunch about the two halves of the house likely to be correct? Or is there another explanation?
2. Are there any advantages/disadvantages to this sort of arrangement?
3. If we wanted to, how much work would it be to get to something simpler? E.g. going to a single meter.
4. Is there any good reason to have the two meters fed by different suppliers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow that is one I had not seen. I have seen similar but not 2 different utilities supplying the power. On this side of the pond a single residence can’t have separate feeds to the same building unless over 400 amps or a single phase and separate 3 phase system (rare) for residential.

Comment: That sounds mostly like a question about rates and tariffs, which is out of our bailiwick here.  The #1 non-financial reason to keep em split is to allow future subdivision, e.g. if you want to do AirBnB, or simply rent the other unit out.  Beware: the 2 services *may be on different phases, meaning 416V across them, not 230V*.  Any circuit that gets hot from a service must get neutral from the same service.

Comment: Buy some switching gear and a UPS and you could set up the world's smallest and quaintest compute hosting center with redundant utility supplies.  Just for bragging rights :)

Comment: Does the house as a whole generally need rewiring?  Is the wiring very old, or inadequate?  What are the fixed costs of each electric bill, i.e., what would the bill be if you used no electricity for a month?   What are the rates from each provider?  Are they actually physically independent?  If you follow the feeds from the meters do they go off to different poles (or conduits) and from there to different substations (this will be harder to ascertain if they go underground) ?  Is there any mixing? IE if you turn of each supply in turn do clearly demarcated parts of the house go dark?

Comment: @jay613 Yes, from my inexpert examination, the whole house probably could do with rewiring. There's a mix of old and new sockets and a fair few thick unterminated wires wrapped in tape.

Comment: The reason I asked about rewiring, along with other questions, is the situation might not call for a highly proactive change but if there is no economic or other benefit to having two electricity suppliers AND you are rewiring and have the opportunity to put in a new consumer unit, the decision might be to eliminate one.  If the house is reasonably wired you could make one of these a sub of the other.  If the supplies are truly independent and the house is properly wired for that, and you're not paying big fixed costs, you could maintain a redundant electric supply .. that would be very cool.

Comment: @EdBeal does that only apply to new construction, or does it mean that a duplex being converted into a single home would need potentially extensive rewiring to route everything to a single feed?

Comment: When the duplex was converted the conversion changed the occupancy so at that time under the National Electric Code used in the US it would need to be changed.  I have wired a few homes with 3 phase and single phase. The residential portion could have no contact other than the grounding system that had to be common. I have done it where the residence was from a separate meter 2 different homes same owner another fed from a transformer on the 3 phase 480  supply and the last type was a 208 3 phase wye that had a double pole breaker feeding a separate house panel. But never different utility’s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:Hunch would appear to be likely correct.

2C:Cons: *Probably* costs more per month to have two services. You'd have to check. There's typically a charge per service and a charge for use, at least in my part of the world, and I expect that to be similar elsewhere.

Shutting of "the power" in an emergency is not one place, but two.

Increased risks if someone less than fully knowledgeable about the weirdness in this house does any electrical work.

2P:Pros: depending how separate the two providers really are (if they use separate distribution) might be less chance of a power outage affecting both sides of the house (this does not apply if they use the same shared distribution network and are merely separate entities that put power into and sell it from the shared grid.)

3:I'd guess it might be a paperwork nightmare. You'd have to choose a utility to keep and contact both (or all three if you can and do choose a third one) to work out the details. To actually solve 1, you might need rewiring so that one meter feeds both entrance points, otherwise you might be paying for two services to the same provider.

4:Probably not, other than the implications of 3 and 2P, if 2P even applies.

Comment: For #4 just wondering if he is right on border of two power companies and the previous separated cottages were in two different zones/areas till the wall was knocked out/passage made.

Comment: There's *definitely* increased risks here -- it could be possible to wind up with two different circuits in the same box, 400V apart, due to the two services being fed from different phases of the LV network in the area!

Comment: @crip659 @ Ecnerwal - Based on my understanding of the UK electrical system, I think it's unlikely that the two meters are fed by physically isolated distribution. So, based on this answer, it seems unlikely there's any benefit from keeping this arrangement and some considerable risks.